# How to publish a Page and Posts using single template

Tags: templates

Does anyone know how to structure a WP template in the loop by:

Publishing the page content on top, immediate followed by certain category posts underneath the page content?

Seems like it should be straight forward. I have not been able to locate any help on it.

Thank you.

**Here's what I pulled together so far:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page & Posts
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="page">
    <div class="content">
        <article class="article">
            <div id="content_box">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('g post'); ?>>
                    <div class="single_page">
                        <?php if ($options['mts_breadcrumb'] == '1') { ?>
                            <div class="breadcrumb"><?php the_breadcrumb(); ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <header>
                            <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        </header>
                        <div class="post-content box mark-links">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="post excerpt">
                        <header>
                            <span class="thecomment">
                                <p><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"> <?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></a></p>
                            </span>                     
                            <h2 class="title">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h2>
                            <?php if($options['mts_headline_meta'] == '1') { ?>
                                <div class="post-info"> 
                                    <span class="thetime"><?php _e('Written on ',''); the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span>
                                    <span class="theauthor"><?php _e('by ',''); the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
                                    <span class="thecategory"><?php _e(' in ',''); the_category(', ') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </header>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" id="featured-thumbnail">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> 
                                <?php echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail('featured',array('title' => '')); echo '</div>'; ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="post-content image-caption-format-1">
                            <?php echo excerpt(53);?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="readMore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php _e('Read More',''); ?></a></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>   
                <?php if ($options['mts_pagenavigation'] == '1') { ?>
                    <?php pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="pnavigation2">
                        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; '.'Older posts', '' ) ); ?></div>
                        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts'.' &rarr;', '' ) ); ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You going to have to use 2 loops here using WP_Query, that's my guess.

Comment: You can use `get_posts` or `WP_Query` with two loops.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for related post below your post, or just category posts from a specific category in general

Answer (score 4):

This *is* very straightforward, at least from development point of view.

1. You need to create [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for the page.
2. Main [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) will take care of page itself.
3. Follow it by adding secondary loop with arguments for set of posts you need.

Comment: @H.Ferrence Codex has quite a few examples of loops and templates, if you are still having trouble you can elaborate on your question by adding your code progress to it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code snippet for the second loop:

```
<?php $args = array (
    'cat' => array ( 1,2,3 ), //replace with your category ids
    'posts_per_page' => 5 //change it as needed
   );
$category_posts = new WP_Query ( $args );

if( $category_posts->have_posts() ):
    while( $category_posts->have_posts() ):
        $category_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; 
endif; ?>
```

Use your css selectors to style it perfectly. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the example loop, but no need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` as the `new WP_Query` gets saved into its own variable and does not interfere with the main `$wp_query` and the `$wp_the_query` contents.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks for the info. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

UPDATE:  Do not use this answer.  I recommend you use the answer provided by @The Sufi below.

@H.Ferrence:  I highly recommend you "un-accept" this answer

Comment: Your example is basically useless as it uses `query_posts` which should not be used at all, specially in this instance. `WP_Query` should be used in this instance

Comment: "specially in this instance"  -- What's special about this instance?

Comment: Answers on [wordpress.se] are supposed to have all the necessary information included - link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: It might be working, but there is a better way to do it, for the *why* read [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/22534) and [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/22534). @H.Ferrence

Comment: @H.Ferrence : The solution might appear to do what you want but [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) clobbers the main query which can ___break other things___ on your site. It ___should not ever___ be used, and I hope it is removed from Core eventually.

Comment: And as already noted, being a link only answer this question violates site quality guidelines. See: [help].

Comment: @s_ha_dum:  The original poster was looking for help, the link and my additional comment got him what he needed.  I guess I could have copy and pasted instead.  Though I suppose just telling him to use two loops and WP_Query is much more helpful and well within the site's quality guidelines.  Next time I'll try harder to help the poster find an answer to his problem instead of providing useless links and commentary.

Comment: Links die. The only meaningful content of your answer is the second paragraph, and that’s just a comment, not a solution. Please update your answer. See also: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: leromt, @H.Ferrence sometimes we have to admit when we are wrong. This can even be on answers that have received a lot of attention and upvotes and there [even is a badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/disciplined) as reward for admitting when we are wrong. We all learn from asking, answering, failing and trying again. That's maybe the main benefit of community knowledge and discussion. And yes, answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: toscho: Excellent point about links dying.  
@kaiser:  I never said I wasn't wrong, I merely pointed out that my response did in fact help the poster. I now understand the intent of not providing only links and I'll abide by it (this was my first attempt at an answer).   I've tried to delete the answer but apparently I can't.

Comment: leromt, thanks for helping making that site worth a readers time :) I hope that doesn't hold you back from any further efforts on other questions. Such things happen to the best of us (on a regular basis :)